# Count if a range of cells contains a certain month

Tags: excel-formula, countif, isnumeric

I have a list that contains dates in M/DD/YYYY format.

In another sheet (see first image), i want to be able to calculate how many times a certain month appears in that list.

The formula i thought would work is 
`=COUNTIFS(*date range sheet&cells*,ISNUMBER(*date range sheet&cells*),*date range sheet&cells*,(MONTH(*date range sheet&cells*)=1))`

In this case, the 1 would be for January, 2 for February and so on.

**I am using a countifs because i have another if statement already worked out that i need to combine with this one: `(*Date range sheet&another column*),"Loss")`**

[image: Output table]
[image: Data range]

***Thank you all***

Answer (score 0):

With dates in column **A**, in **C1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$1:$A$27)=ROW()))
```

and copy down through **C12**:

[image]

**C1** are the January counts
**C2** are the February counts
etc.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but a sumproduct only works if i dont have another if statement to merge with this. i need to essentially nest the month formula in an countifs statement

Comment: @mattrashty  If you explain the other formula, perhaps we can merge them

Comment: The other formula is simple....Date range sheet (another column),"Loss") .....If the date is paired with another column that contains the word Loss, i want it to count. If the column contains a different word, i want it excluded.